# How to fix that dhclient uses massive amounts of bandwidth when bridging eth0 to wlan0?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, ethernet

I have been using my Raspberry Pi as a WiFi adapter for my PS3, because the internal WiFi adapter on the PS3 isn't good, but the USB adapter on the Raspberry Pi is much better. I have been using these commands to do it:

First, I install wicd network manager and configure it in the LXDE desktop environment:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

Then I install the bridge utilities and make the bridge:

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
sudo ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0
sudo ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
sudo brctl addif br0 wlan0
sudo dhclient br0
```

After using these commands the bridge works great. But after leaving the Raspberry Pi on overnight with no traffic from eth0, the Raspberry Pi starts using a massive amount of bandwidth on my network, and no other devices on the network work until I unplug the Raspberry Pi. I would like to be able to run the Raspberry Pi all the time, so I don't have to configure the Raspberry Pi every time I want to use the PS3.

Answer (score 0):

OK, something to help this is you could go into WICD network manager and switch drivers to the "none" option. By default it is wext which has been deprecated. When you select none it doesn't pass any custom drivers such as wext to wpa_supplicant, it just uses the one already in raspbian. I would also recommend not overclocking as that seemed to exacerbate this problem, but I don't know for sure.